# How to Use data members of base class as derived class' constructor? (in C++)

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to use data members of base class as my derived class' constructor, but there seems to be an error whenever I try to run the program. Below is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
protected:
    string title;
    string author;
public:
    Book(string t, string a)
    {
        title = t;
        author = a;
    }
};

class MyBook: public Book
{
protected:
    int price;
public:
    MyBook(string T, string A, int P): Book(title, author)
    {

        price = P;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << author << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    MyBook One("abc", "def", 2);
    One.display();
}
```

What seems to be my fault at creating this derived class' constructor?

Comment: Don't tag spam unless you're trying to draw negative attention to your question.

Comment: [Please do not tag multiple languages in your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question/) unless your question is specifically about these languages.  You may think it will lead to a faster answer, but the reality is that it is more likely to lead to a faster closure.

Comment: ok, got it. Actually my first time using stack overflow. I'm not in a rush for an answer, I'm just a beginner in terms of programming, just learning things on my own. What a world to live in. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you write:

```
MyBook(string T, string A, int P): Book(title, author)
```

What I guess you actually want:

```
MyBook(string T, string A, int P): Book(T, A)
```

The `:Book(T, A)` part is to pass arguments to the base class constructor. `title` and `author` are not defined here, but `T` and `A` are defined.

A possible source of confusion is that `title` and `author` happens to be the names used inside the base class. You should note that you are passing information from derived class constructor to base class constructor, not the other way round. So the derived class constructor should tell the base class constructor about `T` and `A`.

Comment: @Jayy You may consider upvote every answer you deem helpful, and "tick" the best one as "accepted". That's how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

MyBook(string T, string A, int P): Book(title, author) is wrong
title and author are not recognized there. Use T and A:
 MyBook(string T, string A, int P): Book(T, A)